# How do I install the latest version of okular?

Tags: 10.10, okular

The version of okular on my ubuntu 10.10 is 0.11.2, while the website shows the latest version to be 0.14

My question is - how do I get the latest version?

My update manager does not show any updates for okular although I dont know why.

If there is a .deb package for okular 0.14 that I can install please let me know. I wish to avoid compiling it from source myself.

Comment: I'm sure you are probably already aware, but 10.10 is now out of support.  You may wish to consider upgrading your version of ubuntu... - just a thought :)

Comment: @fossfreedom: Yes I know, but Ubuntu 11.10 (& 12.04) comes with linux kernel 3 which overheats my laptop and hence I wish to stick to 10.10.

Comment: Maybe the problem of overheating is not related to kernel 3 but to some configuration that kernel 3 brings by default. I mean, if you set up the same configurations in kernel 3 like the one's you have now, you shouldn't experience that overheating problem.
As to the question, you could download the .deb file of that version or even extract the source and compile it yourself.

Comment: There was a kernel bug at one point that caused some overheating.  If you haven't tried 12.04 recently, and you're not opposed to doing so, try it again when it hits stable.

Answer (score 3):

To have the latest version of Okular you have 3 options:

**Easy Option** - Install the latest Kubuntu. Either 11.10 or wait for 12.04. The reason for this will be explained in the other Options.

**Intermediate Option** - Download the DEB Package of Okular and all of it's dependencies and the dependencies of those dependencies until you have literally downloaded KDE in pieces just to install that since the latest Okular depends on libraries and other packages that also depend on others that need to be a specific version or newer. This versions are not compatible with an older Ubuntu so you would have to start downloading a lot of packages. This in most cases will not work and waste your time since at some point a package might say "Hey I need a newer kernel version of autotool, autoconf, make... and so on." So your chances of having it work there are very difficult.

**Difficult Option** - Compile the whole thing from scratch. This option will take more experience and a heck of more time to do and at the end it will not guarantee that it will work on the kernel used in Ubuntu 10.10 with the versions of the tools provided in 10.10.

To make matters worse, 10.10 has been discontinued. So try the option everyone has suggested (Install 12.04). If you do not want a heavy system then install Lubuntu or Xubuntu and then install Okular from there but just so you know, you can install Okular very easy and with less download time in Ubuntu 12.04 since it already comes with the QT libraries for it. No need to download them when trying to download Okular.

Comment: I am trying to [compile Okular from scratch but fail on Ubuntu Precise](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162166/freetype-notfound-error-when-trying-to-build-okular-from-source). Could you take a look at my question, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should try kubuntu 12.04 as it is pretty stable and has the latest release of okular. I have used it since beta1 and there has been no issues as crashes. Moreover the bug in the kernel which overheats the laptops is resolved in 3.2 series of the kernel.