# Compiling a program from source

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling

I have a basic question concerning packages and the possibility to build a program in Ubuntu. To make it concrete: I'm using *Ubuntu 18.04.6 LT*S. Say I want to build Okular from the source to have the latest features [ [okular from source](https://okular.kde.org/build-it/) ]. There are some related questions on this topic, see [Q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120996/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-okular), [Q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162166/freetype-notfound-error-when-trying-to-build-okular-from-source), but what I would like to know is: When starting downloading the needed dependencies (e.g. I need *cmake_3.18.4-2_amd64.deb*, and this needs *libarchive13_3.4.3-2+b1_amd64.deb* and so on...) how can I check if, at some point, I need an newer kernel? Because this would be the ultimate end, right (since at this point I should really directly install a never OS)? I'm not sure to which extend `apt` is doing this job. Does `apt`'s output

```
 ...
     cmake : Depends: libarchive13 (>= 3.3.3) but 3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.7 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
     Depends: libjsoncpp24 (>= 1.9.4) but it is not installable
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed

 ...
```

mean exactly this, namely that it is hopeless to install all the needed dependencies to succeed? I don't dread a lot of work but I would like to know in advance if it is a waste of time to build the package by myself. What is the best procedure here (except from a system update)?

Comment: Why are you downloading packages manually7 Run `sudo apt install build-essential` and all dependencies will be installed. Or install at lease `cmake`.

Comment: @Pilot6: This output is from installing `cmake_3.18.4-2_amd64.deb`. So, should I proceed or is it hopeless?

Comment: @Pilot6: And by the way, I have installed `build-essential`...

Comment: `sudo apt install cmake` Apt should take care of dependencies.

Comment: @Pilot6: Well, this is of course something I already did, here is the output:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: cmake-data (= 3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.2) but 3.18.4-2 is to be installed`

Comment: So, back to my question: Is it worth it to proceed?

Comment: It is probably because you downloaded and install some wrong version manually.

Comment: Remove `cmake` and install it again. The 3.18 version is not for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I see, where can I check whether it is for Ubuntu 18.04 or not? I indeed installed 3.18 from the Debian repo

Comment: When mucking about with different versions, it's often helpful to use a Container or VM (or in Python a venv) to prevent all the weird versions from polluting your base system.

Comment: Since you installed build-essential, try `rmadison`. Example: `rmadison cmake` will tell you versions and matching releases of Ubuntu. `rmadison -u debian cmake` will tell you the same for Debian.

Comment: @user535733 `rmadison cmake` tells me that the highest version of `cmake` I can have for Ubuntu 18.04 is  `3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.2`. Since CMake 3.16 or higher is required for the Okular build there is no way to install it, right?

Comment: There's almost always a way. But it's telling you that particular path won't be easy. By the time you have upgraded dependencies, you will essentially be running 21.04 or 21.10...and getting there might be very ugly. Maybe that's not the path you want. Most documentation for building assumes you want up-to-date software, which means you need up-to-date dependencies.

Comment: @user535733 But this is exactly the point. What does "path won't be easy" tell me? Can it fail or is it simply installing a lot of dependencies? It is this fuzziness which is unnecessary.

Comment: It's fuzzy because we have not tested what you are doing. You are off the marked path. My opinion is that you will destroy your system trying to install bleeding-edge software into a 3-year-old Debian-based system. You won't be able to reconcile all of the dependency conflicts that you will create. However, I have not tested that. I might be flat wrong.

Comment: @user535733 I'm asking this since I'm thinking of the following scenario: Say you a running a cluster on Debian 10 where it is not that simple to update the OS (downtime etc.). When should I say: Here I can risk a compilation from source to get a newer version of some package?

Comment: Debian 10 is off-topic here. On Ubuntu use flatpak as described in below answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compile very new software on not-so-very old system because of dependencies. Manual installation of new dependencies on old system will break it.

As not-harmful alternative you can use [Okular 21.08.2 flatpak from KDE](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.okular) instead on your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak install flathub org.kde.okular
```

And to start it use

```
flatpak run org.kde.okular
```

or find relevant icon in your desktop environment.

Comment: ...and to start it: `flatpak run org.kde.okular`

Comment: So: flatpak or snap? Somehow your comment, N0rbert, was deleted...

Answer (score -1):

KDE already solved this problem with the Okular Snap.

https://snapcraft.io/okular

The Snap is sandboxed from the rest of your system, and will auto-update whenever the author (KDE) pushes an update.

The current snap (version 20.12.3) should be fully compatible with your 18.04 system.

- For additional information: `snap list okular`
- To install: `sudo snap install okular`
- It's independent of Ubuntu (or Debian) versions. If you discover that the snap is stale, simply ping KDE directly -- they're the author, and they can update it anytime.